# scrape multiple clubs per player in one cell of the java script table - display both in the same list element

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

My problem is, that in the last cell of the javascript table, I get the clubs the player played for via the "img".

```
injury_list = []
season_list = []
day_list = []
missedgame_list = []
team_list = [] 
player_list = []
```

```
 url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.ch/emre-can/verletzungen/spieler/119296/ajax/yw1/page1'
    response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom5'})
    injury_data = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(injury_data, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find(id="yw1")
    
    injurytypes = table.select("td[class='hauptlink bg_rot_20']") + table.select("td[class='hauptlink']")
    all_injuries = [injury.text for injury in injurytypes]
    injury_list.extend(all_injuries)
  
    
    seasons =  table.select("td[class='zentriert bg_rot_20']") + table.select("td[class='zentriert']")
    all_seasons = [season.text for season in seasons]
    season_list.extend(all_seasons)
        
    days = table.select("td[class='rechts bg_rot_20']") + table.select("td[class='rechts']")
    all_days =[float(day.text.split()[0]) for day in days]
    day_list.extend(all_days)
        
    missedgames = table.select("td[class='rechts hauptlink wappen_verletzung bg_rot_20']") + table.select("td[class='rechts hauptlink wappen_verletzung']")
    all_missedgames = [float(missedgame.text.replace("-", "0")) for missedgame in missedgames]
    missedgame_list.extend(all_missedgames)
    
    for item in table.select('img', class_='tiny_wappen', recursive=True): 
            team_list.append(item.get('alt'))
```

i need a dataframe with the different cell entries and that when there are two clubs, I have both clubs in the same dataframe cell Juventus Turin / Borussia Dortmund.
Otherwise I have a problem, that the code returns lists from different lenght, respectively not everything fits togehter in a dataframe.

I already tried it with if loops to indicate that if there are two img in one cell etc. but did not succeed.

Thank you very much.

```
season_list_def = season_list[0::3]
startdate_list = season_list[1::3]
enddate_list = season_list[2::3]
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"injurytype": injury_list, "season": season_list_def, "injury_start": startdate_list, "injury_end": enddate_list, "absence_duration": day_list, "missed_games": missedgame_list, "Team": np.nan})
df.loc[df["missed_games"] != 0, "Team"] = team_list #this is not working because the lenght of team list is not from equal size because I have two clubs in one cell. 
df
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You are working with a list called `team_list` but talking about a dataframe. What **exactly** is your expected output?

Comment: in the end I will make out of different lists a dataframe - I scrap all information from the table in different lists

Comment: So the first step is just to get the whole table?

Comment: I already have the whole table - all injuries and all dates and the season. I just did not put the whole code. The problem is that when there are two clubs indicated, the list has to seperate elements but I want to have the cell with the two clubs into one element. With the code I have I get all the clubs but all in seperate list elements.

Comment: I want to append exactly one item per iteration and in the case where there are two clubs, both of them

Comment: Again, instead of **describing** what you want, can you edit your question and actually showi the **exact** expected output?

Comment: I did it now. sorry for the inconvenience